# Swift won't recognize /n line breaks after base64 string decoding

Tags: ios, swift, base64, line-breaks

I am trying to take my base64 decoded string and print it, but the result does not recognize the line breaks. For example,

```
print("Hi \n hello \n hi")
```

**Print like this**

```
Hi
hello
hi
```

As expected, but when I decode the encoded version of the string, and print the result, it returns the string without the line breaks recognized. Here is my code.

```
var encodedString = "SGkgXG4gaGVsbG8gXG4gaGk="

let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: encodedString, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters),
        decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

print (decodedString!)
 // prints "Hi \n hello \n hi"
```

How do I change my code to allow Swift to recognize these line breaks? Thanks!

Comment: how you encoded your string ?

Comment: In my code it is encoded using the PHP function base64_encode($str), but the string in my example is encoded using base64encode.org. Both ways of encoding print "Hi \n hello \n hi".

Comment: @NeilJohnson So you are getting this `encodedString` from server response?

Comment: Yes from a JSON response from my MySQL database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string is not encoded properly, I have checked your string `encodedString` in playground when you decode it `decodedString` contain string like this way `Hi \\n hello \\n hi`, it is escaping the `\n` thats why it is printing `\n` with output. Try to encode properly string like this way.

```
var str = "Hi \n hello \n hi"
let utf8str = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
if let base64Encoded = utf8str?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
{
    let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64Encoded, options: []),
    decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print (decodedString!)
}
```

**Edit:** The problem is here is string is encode in `PHP` and you are decoding in the app with swift. Your decoding string contain `\\n` instead of `\n` means it is escaping the `\n` character one way to solve is `replace` `\\n` with `\n` but it is not preferable but right not it will work for you like this way.

```
var str = decodedString!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\n", withString: "\n")
print (str)
```

**Note:** It is batter if you `encode/decode` both on the same side means either on your `PHP` or the application side with swift.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! I know it is not 'reusable' code, but it will have to do for now. I upvoted, but my reputation is not high enough for it to be publicly visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
Base64.DEFAULT;  //Include \n
Base64.NO_WRAP;   //Not included \n
```

This parameter perhaps also found in Swift, but my solution is totally uses Base64.NO_ WRAP;

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with swift, but I tried in objective-c and got the result correctly. You can convert the code to swift...

```
NSString *str = @"Hi \n hello \n hi";
NSLog(@"Original Str value: %@", str);

// Encoding the string value
NSData *encodeData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *base64String = [encodeData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"Encode String Value: %@", base64String);

// Decoding the encoded string value
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Decode String Value: %@", decodedString);
```

Output:

[image]

Happy coding...